# Link to download a file in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3

I want to send an email with some links to download from my s3 bucket. I have the url of the file stored in a table. How can I use the link_to helper?

```
<%= link_to "Download File x", @profile.document %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because I suppose that `@profile.document` is a full qualified url, you don't need `link_to` helper, simply use:

```
<a href="<%= @profile.document %>">doc</a>`.
```

Use `link_to` when you have a resource instance (like Profile probably) that is defined in the `config/routes.rb` file. For example:

```
resources :profile
```

then when you use

```
<%= link_to 'download', @profile %>
```

you will have

```
http://test.com/profiles/34234
```